# Uniqueness of maximum involving some quadratic functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, maxima-minima, quadratic-forms

A family of positive convex function $\Psi_{\alpha} : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $$\Psi_{\alpha}(x) = A(x) + B(x) + \alpha D(x)$$ with paramter $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$. $A(x),B(x),C(x)$ are all positive,quadratic and convex functions. (edit), Also $A,B,D$ are linearly independent.

Let the unique minimizer of $\Psi_{\alpha}(x)$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ be $x_{\alpha}$. Define $E(\alpha) = B(x_{\alpha})$. It is known that $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}E(\alpha) = 0$ and $\lim_{\alpha\to \infty}E(\alpha) = 0$.

I want to know if I can show that there exists a unique maximum of $E(\alpha)$, over $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$. Existence is clear. Uniqueness need to be proved.

Comment: Taking $A(x) = B(x) = D(x) = x^2$ leads to $x_\alpha = 0, E(\alpha) = 0$ independently on $\alpha$. You might want to add some conditions on $A, B, C$ like linear independence maybe to get something more interesting.

Comment: Korf : Thank you. $A(x)$ is linearly independent to both $B(x)$ and $D(x)$. Also $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ are not the same. (not equal except on a countable set) (actual motivation is this [problem][1]). Not necessary to read that problem, just fyi. [1]:  [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306993/2987]